# Rearranging Windows Within Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Emacs tends to open two horizontally separated windows, one on top of the other (I think windows is the proper emacs term). Since I am working with a wide screen I find it easier and better to work with two vertically separated windows, arranged side by side within the emacs frame.

I know how to open a new vertically separated window using `C-x 3` but how do you rearrange windows that emacs opens itself (for example when `M-x compile` is invoked opening a compilation/debugging window) from horizontal to vertical?

Comment: which version of emacs.? IIRC emacs 24 switched to side by side split

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is what I currently use. Just drop it into your Emacs init file:

```
;; The default behaviour of `display-buffer' is to always create a new
;; window. As I normally use a large display sporting a number of
;; side-by-side windows, this is a bit obnoxious.
;;
;; The code below will make Emacs reuse existing windows, with the
;; exception that if have a single window open in a large display, it
;; will be split horisontally.

(setq pop-up-windows nil)

(defun my-display-buffer-function (buf not-this-window)
  (if (and (not pop-up-frames)
           (one-window-p)
           (or not-this-window
               (not (eq (window-buffer (selected-window)) buf)))
           (> (frame-width) 162))
      (split-window-horizontally))
  ;; Note: Some modules sets `pop-up-windows' to t before calling
  ;; `display-buffer' -- Why, oh, why!
  (let ((display-buffer-function nil)
        (pop-up-windows nil))
    (display-buffer buf not-this-window)))

(setq display-buffer-function 'my-display-buffer-function)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `split-height-threshold` and the `split-height-threshold` variables, both customizable.

For further information on what values they take, <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `split-window-sensibly` <kbd>RET</kbd>. [This Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#index-split_002dwindow_002dsensibly-2293) touches the topic superficially.

This affects how `display-buffer` works, which probably `compile` and many other commands use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
(defun split-window-prefer-side-by-side (&optional window)
  (let ((split-height-threshold (and (< (window-width window)
                                        split-width-threshold)
                                     split-height-threshold)))
    (split-window-sensibly window)))

(setq split-window-preferred-function 'split-window-prefer-side-by-side)
```

This still consults `split-*-threshold` variable values, just prefers side-by-side windows when both splitting directions are acceptable.